# getting GEOErrorDomain code=-204 error with xcode simulator ios 6 - working with mapkit

Tags: ios6, mapkit

I've just created a project with iOS 6 SDK and I'm working with new Apple maps but even with a very basic initialization, I mean, just added the framework put the map in xib and connected the mapview with the IBOutlet, it loads the map fine showing Cupertino location, but if I move to another point, the tiles won't load anymore and an error begins to show in the console:

```
Operation could not be completed...GEOErrorDomain code= -204
```

It's very annoying. I'm also trying to make zoom over specific coordinates but it's not working either.

Is there anything missing in the configuration or in the code?

Thanks  in advance!